# Cannot resolve DbContext constructor - database creation error

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, code-first, entity-framework-core

In my code the EF7 is not creating the actual proper sqlite database. I'm assuming one root for the problems could be the following error, first the code snippet:.

```
public class Database : DbContext
{ 
    public Database()
        : base("Database")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = "test2.sqlite" };
        var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
        var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connection);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I'm using WPF and entity framework 7 with Sqlite. The error which I'm receiving while trying to compile the code is as follows:

> Cannot resolve constructor 'DbContext(string)', candidates are: 
>   DbContext(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextOptions) (in
>   class DbContext) DbContext(System.IServiceProvider) (in class
>   DbContext)

I'm calling the database in **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Database _context = new Database();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _context.Devices.Add(new Device
        {
            ProductCode = "100",
            TimeCreated = DateTime.Now
        });
        _context.SaveChanges();
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource deviceViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("DeviceViewSource")));

        //_context.Devices.Include(d => d.Name).Load();
        //deviceViewSource.Source = _context.Devices.GetLocal();
        //deviceViewSource.Source = _context.Categories.GetLocal();
    }
```

My code compiles without the `:base("Database")` definition but even if the *.sqlite file is created, it does not have any tables and throws this exception:

> "SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Device'"

Table configuration code I left out of this question, can add it if needed. Plain console test application works without problems.

Edit: I'm using code first approach to create the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a call to

```
_context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

This will ensure 1. the files are there and 2. the tables are created.

:caution: Do not call this in the constructor for your DbContext.

Comment: This is correct solution. Also good to point out the difference between `Database.EnsureCreated()` and `Database.Migrate()`  I found a post discussing about this matter [EF7 EnsureCreated vs. Migrate Methods](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/ef7-ensurecreated-vs-migrate-methods/)